# How to ignore False, so it doesn't count as 0

Tags: python

is there a way to make 0 not to be the same as False?
    Because I keep getting the wrong result and I couldn't find a solution 
    yet.

```
def move_zeros(array):    
    a = 0
    for i in array:
        if array[a] == 0:
            array.remove(array[a])
            array.append(0)
            a +=1
        else:
            a += 1         
    return array    

print(move_zeros([0,1,None,2,False,1,0]))
```

**Input array:**

```
[0,1,None,2,False,1,0]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[1,None,2,False,1,0,0]
```

**Actual output:**

```
[1, None, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Why don't you try replacing False with a string "F" or "False" this will prevent python to consider as 0

Comment: @h4z3 is it bad to delete an element? I would like to know why.

Comment: @psn1997 I am doing training on codewars and replacing it with "F" will output a false result too. I can paste the question if u want.

Comment: Add a condition on data type: `if isinstance(array[a], int) and array[a] == 0`

Comment: @Plopp Have you checked `isinstance(array[a], int)`? This will result as `True`

Comment: @Plopp  ok I tried but still gave me the same result xD.

Comment: @shaikmoeed right, should use a not instance of bool instead of instance of int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean type inherit from int type, so False is 0, but of a different type. This means you can distinguish 0 from False with a type check. False and bool, and therefore int, but 0 is not a bool.

Also, `.remove` removes first value equal to the value, so even with this check the code didn't work. ;) It took first 0, no matter the value of `a`, so it also grabbed False. Let's just use `del`

```
def move_zeros(array):    
    a = 0
    for i in array:
        if array[a] == 0 and not isinstance(array[a], bool):
            del array[a]
            array.append(0)
            # a +=1 if you remove an element, next one jumps in its place, so you have to check the same index
        else:
            a += 1         
    return array    

print(move_zeros([0,1,None,2,False,1,0]))
```

Output:

```
[1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterating on a list while updating it often leads to problems, so you should avoid it.

Just build a list of non-zero values in a list comprehension and append the needed zeros:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    out = [v for v in array if v != 0 or v is False]
    out.extend([0] * (len(array) - len(out)))
    return out
```

Note that `0` and `False` are equal, so `0 == False`, but they are different objects, so `0 is not False`.

Test with your data:

```
print(move_zeros([0,1,None,2,False,1,0]))
# [1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0]
```

Another test case that will fail with some solutions iterating on the list while updating it:

```
move_zeros([0,1,None, 0, 0, 2,False,1,0])
# [1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: excellent point about test  cases that fail in other solutions offered (including mines)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the additional clause `is not False` to distinguish between 0 and False.

```py
def move_zeros(array):    
    zeroLocations = [i for i in range(len(array)) if array[i] == 0 and array[i] is not False]   
    zeroLocations.reverse() 
    for zeroId in zeroLocations:
        del array[zeroId] 
        array.append(0) 
    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type of the element your working with so only if element is not a bool and is equal to 0 then it will be removed and a 0 appended to the list.

```
def move_zeros(input):
    for index, element in enumerate(input):
        if element == 0 and not isinstance(element, bool):
            input.pop(index)
            input.append(0)

    return input

print(move_zeros([0,1,None,2,False,1,0]))
```

Comment: Thierry provides a more complete example and shows flaws in my answer however i will leave it here for completness to highlight the flaw.